# Building cordova Android on windows 10 ..but ionic cordova build Android throws error shown below

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have  built an app using ionic cordova 
want to add qrcode functionality...so used barcode plugin of cordova 

following is the steps I followed:
1.created project
2.cordova platform add android
3.cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git
4.ionic cordova build android
(have installed gradle)//here is where error occured
the following is the error`ionic cordova build android

> cordova build android
>   ? Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

```
Discovered plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it
again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner@2.0.0 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yash jain\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-15T05_11_58_022Z-debug.log
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\yash
    jain\Documents\GitHub\learningmitra\school\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js" "C:\Users\yash
jain\Documents\GitHub\learningmitra\school"
    add to body class: platform-android
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_101
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Unzipping C:\Users\yash jain\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip
    to C:\Users\yash jain\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```